# How to view type providers in the assembly

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am looking through the object explorer and trying to find out where/how the type providers are defined - I am looking through FSharp.Data.dll. It shows CsvFile and CsvRow.. but I could not find CsvProvider. Where is that defined ? Should I  rely only on the documentation to find out what type providers are in a given assembly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FSharp.Data.dll` is the run-time component of `FSharp.Data`. Type-providers generates types for you during compile-time and is after that not needed. That dll is called: `FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll`.

You could decompile that dll but I think it's easier to just look at the source code: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Json/JsonProvider.fs

What the type provider does is that it injects code and types that makes navigating JSON convenient for you. Using a tool like `dnSpy` one can find out what is actually happening

So the example program

```
type Simple = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>
let f (s: string) =
  let s = Simple.Parse s
  s.Name
```

After decompiling it to C# using `dnSpy` looks like this:

```
    public static string f(string s)
    {
        IJsonDocument s2 = (IJsonDocument)JsonDocument.Create(new StringReader(s));
        JsonValueOptionAndPath jsonValueOptionAndPath = JsonRuntime.TryGetPropertyUnpackedWithPath(s2, "name");
        return JsonRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<string>(jsonValueOptionAndPath.Path, JsonRuntime.ConvertString("", jsonValueOptionAndPath.JsonOpt), jsonValueOptionAndPath.JsonOpt);
    }
```

So the string is parsed into a `IJsonDocument` and then `s.Name` is turned into

```
    JsonValueOptionAndPath jsonValueOptionAndPath = JsonRuntime.TryGetPropertyUnpackedWithPath(s2, "name");
    return JsonRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<string>(jsonValueOptionAndPath.Path, JsonRuntime.ConvertString("", jsonValueOptionAndPath.JsonOpt), jsonValueOptionAndPath.JsonOpt);
```

The code about doesn't need `FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll` so it's not included in the build.

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed reply. I am using F# interactive mostly and referencing the library through #r directive. So, if I understood  your explanations correctly,, FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll will not get generated during F# interactive use as there is no compile action  (or it will be generated in the background, not visible to us). And that we really need to look at the source code check whether a given assembly has the type provider.